# Change style of one single element using XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt, tei

I am completely new to  using XSLT, but in my job they're asking me to do a little XSL Transformation. Please forgive me if my question is too basic.

I work with handwritten poetry and I'd like to see every verse (*l* element, inside *lg*) as a line. Verses could include several elements, such as abbreviations (*abbr*), deletions (*del*), additions (*add*) and other elements. I need these elements to be shown in different colors inside each verse.

This is part of the code I've been able to write so far.

```
<xsl:template match = "TEI/text/body/lg">
  <p><xsl:apply-templates select = "l" /></p>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="l" priority="0">
    <span style="color:black;">
      <xsl:value-of select="." />
    </span><br/>
  </xsl:template>
```

Hope you can help.

Comment: Please show a sample of your input and your desired output. Do you know what HTML markup you want to generate? If so, this is an XSLT question. If not, then it's an HTML question. For an XSLT question, you should describe the desired output in HTML markup terms, not in terms of the final rendered appearance in the browser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try the following solution:

Given this input, which appears to be encoded in the TEI (*Text Encoding Initiative*) format:

```xml
<TEI xmlns="http://www.tei-c.org/ns/1.0">
  <teiHeader>
      <fileDesc>
         <titleStmt>
            <title>Title</title>
         </titleStmt>
         <publicationStmt>
            <p>Information about publication or distribution</p>
         </publicationStmt>
         <sourceDesc>
            <p>Information about the source</p>
         </sourceDesc>
      </fileDesc>
  </teiHeader>
  <text>
      <body>
         <lg>
            <l>Roses are <abbr>red</abbr></l>
            <l>Violets are <del>blue</del></l>
            <l>Line <add>three</add></l>
         </lg>
         <lg>
            <l>Roses are red</l>
            <l>Line two</l>
            <l>Line three</l>
         </lg>
      </body>
  </text>
</TEI>
```

the following stylesheet:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
    xmlns:tei="http://www.tei-c.org/ns/1.0"
    exclude-result-prefixes="xs tei"
    version="1.0">
    <xsl:output method="html" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
    
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <div class="wrapper">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="tei:TEI/tei:text/tei:body"/>
        </div>
    </xsl:template>
    
    <!--Block elements-->
    
    <xsl:template match="tei:lg">
        <div class="verse" style="padding: 2rem;">
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </div>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="tei:l">
        <div class="verse-line">
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </div>
    </xsl:template>
    
    <!--Inline elements-->
    
    <xsl:template match="tei:abbr">
        <span class="abbr" style="color: red;">
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </span>
    </xsl:template>
    
    <xsl:template match="tei:del">
        <span class="del" style="color: blue;">
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </span>
    </xsl:template>
    
    <xsl:template match="tei:add">
        <span class="add" style="color: cyan;">
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </span>
    </xsl:template>
    
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

will output this HTML:

```html
<div class="wrapper">
   <div class="verse" style="padding: 2rem;">
      <div class="verse-line">Roses are <span class="abbr" style="color: red;">red</span></div>
      <div class="verse-line">Violets are <span class="del" style="color: blue;">blue</span></div>
      <div class="verse-line">Line <span class="add" style="color: cyan;">three</span></div>
      </div>   
   <div class="verse" style="padding: 2rem;">      
      <div class="verse-line">Roses are red</div>
      <div class="verse-line">Line two</div>
      <div class="verse-line">Line three</div>
   </div>
</div>
```

It will work with any of the follwing XSLT processors:

- Saxon6.5.5
- Saxon-HE 9.9.1.7
- Saxon-PE 9.9.1.7
- Saxon-EE 9.9.1.7